# "The latter" to describe the last item in a list

Tags: phrases, expressions

So far, I've used the word "the latter" to distinguish between two items or things. Like in the following sentence:

> “This item is avail­able in wood and in metal, but I pre­fer the
>   former.”

Recently, though, I've been wondering if it is possible to use "latter" to refer to the last item on a longer list? Like in this example:

> "This item is available in wood, plastic, metal and paper. The latter
>   is the least expensive"

What is your take on this issue? Any feedback appereciated!